# javascript client for oauth2 and google-oauth library's "redirect-uri" missing case

Tags: google-api, google-oauth

I am working on porting oauth2client library to google-auth and oauthlib library
Right now for oauth2 authentication, I am using javascript client and using grantofflineaccess method in it.

The flow for oauth2client library was:
using the js client, we get the authorization code and pass it in `oauth2client.client.credentials_from_code` to get the credentials object. In the paramaeters, we pass only clientid,secret,scopes and code. There was no mention of redirect_uri.

Right now I am replacing it with flow
https://google-auth-oauthlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/google_auth_oauthlib.flow.html

This means that I HAVE TO pass redirect_uri to create the flow object, following which I can use flow.fetch_token(code) to get flow.credentials.

Here is my javascript side code (angularJS) (Reference: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference)

```js
// init
gapi.load('auth2', () => {
      const authScopes = {
        client_id: $window.GOOGLE_API_CLIENT_ID,
        scope: scopes.join(' '),
      };

      auth2 = gapi.auth2.init(authScopes);

// When signin button clicked
auth2.grantOfflineAccess({ redirect_uri: 'postmessage', prompt: 'consent' })
      .then((response) => {
        // We enter this when user signins into google account and 'ALLOWS' the scopes. We receive the code in response using which we get the access and refresh token. The below calls are being made to backend
        Something.authenticateUser(response.code).then(() => {
          $scope.sheetsWizard.onLoginSuccess();
```

The backend code: (django)

```py
# Upon receiving the 'code', it calls oauth2client function to get credentials object
credentials = client.credentials_from_code(
      GOOGLE_API_CLIENT_ID,
      GOOGLE_API_CLIENT_SECRET,
      scopes,
      data['code']
```

The above was older code, How the new code looks in the backend (The frontend or angularJS remains the same)

```py
flow = Flow.from_client_config(client_config=dictionary_with_client_credentials, scopes=scopes, redirect_uri='some_website.com')
    
flow.fetch_token(code = data['code'])
credentials = flow.credentials
```

My questions:

1. Is there a method in google-auth that I am missing, so I don't have to pass redirect_uri, and still get at least access_token and refresh_token, after receiving code?
2. in js gapi client, there is a mention of `redirect_uri='postmessage'`, but could not find documentation related to it. What does it mean?

Comment: Please edit your question and include [example.]  Side note: Are you aware that offline access doesn't work with client side Javascript?

Comment: @DaImTo Hey thanks for replying. I have included examples. I can see the warning on the documentation that its deprecated, but right now I am able to get the authorization code. 
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference

Please let me know if I am not giving enough info